# How to send a text inside an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, sms

Is it possible to send a text immediately inside an app. I have implemented the sms send. I just want to bypass the screen where the user has to press send.

Comment: As per my knowledge and experience, iOS will not allow this.. and this is not possible.

Comment: The context obviously makes a huge difference, but you could integrate into a web service for sending a text without using Massages.app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to bypass the MFMessageViewController screen where the user has to tap "send." I assume Apple has designed it this way to prevent an app from potentially spamming a user's contact list.

In addition, there is no way to detect income SMS. Both these features are strictly reserved for the native Messages app.

For more information on sending an SMS on iOS [check this out.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SystemMessaging_TopicsForIOS/Articles/SendinganSMSMessage.html)

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to implement sending and receiving messages within your app using a web service to store and retrieve messages. For example, you could use a messages library like `JSQMessagesViewController` documented [here](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController) and for simplicity's sake, you could use a BaaS like Parse.